# log4j2 PatternLayout Timestamp Format

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I want to specify logging timestamp in a particular format %d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}, but however I manipulate the pattern the timestamp is displayed as '2015-10-19 00:47:15,423'.

Specifying %d{ISO8601} or %d{ABSOLUTE} are taking effect. I am wondering how the timestamp format is picked, when a custom pattern is specified.

If I want to change the comma separator to period, is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used year format in capital letters for this reason the timestamp was falling back to default format.

With this change I can manipulate the timestamp with custom format specifier without any issue.

Answer (score 4):

I used `%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}` and it worked perfectly.

Note that the `T` is within single quotes so that it is output as is.

The `Z` at the end adds the timezone but it can be omitted too.